# Navigation Controller - How to Add in Another View Controller in Xcode?

Tags: iphone, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, controller, navigation

I'm relatively new to iOS programming but I'm learning bit by bit.  I've got two nib files, one is my HomeViewController and the other is called 'ReceiptTableViewController'.  The HomeVC should not have a top nav bar but the ReceiptTableVC should, with a title and 'back' where the user can swipe to go back to HomeVC.

How would I go about adding this?  I've dragged the Navigation Controller to the side of my ReceiptTableVC in the nib file.

I've searched for various answers but some contradict each other as the authors use different versions of Xcode, and some start with storyboards, etc.

Any help is much appreciated!

- I haven't used storyboard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this method to decide whether your navigationBar show or not in your viewController.`[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden: animated:];`

In your `AppDelegate`:

```
UINavigationController *naviController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:homeController];
naviController.navigationBarHidden = YES; //set home controller navigation bar hidden.
self.window.rootViewController = naviController;
```

Then in your `ReceiptTableViewController`'s viewDidLoad method:

```
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:NO]; // show the navigation bar.
```

This is how to declare a `UINavigationController` programmatically. You can have a try.

Comment: Thanks for your help!  Unfortunately it returns an error - 'Use of undeclared intentifier 'animated', so I changed 'animated' to 'NO' thinking it wouldn't be hidden.  That didn't bring any errors but also didn't show the 'back' buttona and the rest of the navbar.

Comment: `[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];`Are you taking animated as a variable??

Comment: I tried that and it still didn't show, am I supposed to link the Navigation Controller to anything after I drag it out in my nib file?  I apologize for my stupidity, I'm new to all this.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: Did you get the normal push behavior when you push the second view controller? I did not declare a navigation controller in xib before.I prefer to do it programly.But I think you should have a subclass of naviagtion controller if you drag on in xib file.