# Change to different VIewController on button press

Tags: ios

I have a functioning app, and I'd like to just add a new view and have an existing button change views with an IBAction function. I've set up the following and get no response. Thanks for any help.

MainViewController.h

```
- (IBAction)showSettings:(UIButton *)sender;
```

MainViewController.m

```
-(void)showSettings:(UIButton*)btn{
    SettingsViewController *oView = [[SettingsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SettingsViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:oView animated:YES];
}
```

SettingsViewController.h (the new view) is relatively empty.

SettingsViewController.m

```
boilerplate
```

Comment: Please don't post boilerplate code. You have nothing in SettingsViewController.m that isn't from the template.

Comment: sorry dude I didn't realize. Figured if I didn't post it someone would surely ask why I didn't post it!

Answer (score 1):

Three things to make sure:

1. `showSettings:` gets called when the button is tapped (if not then perhaps you didn't connect the button tap event to the action at all)
2. `SettingsViewController` instance gets alloc and initialised
3. `self.navigationController` is not nil (if it's nil perhaps the current view controller is not embed in a navigation controller in the first place?).

Update:

Now we see the issue is #3. To embed your first view controller to a UINavigationController so you could push the second view controller:

- Select your first view controller in storyboard
- Select (menu) Editor -> Embed In -> Navigation Controller

Comment: 1. yes its getting called
2. Not sure how to check. 3. I've not added any navigation controller, perhaps that is the problem? I only added a new view controller and xib file, and the button and function to call it.

Comment: @harp, #3 - No perhaps about it, that's the problem.

Comment: Nerver push other veiwController without navigationController. You can do nothing with an nil object.

Comment: @harp, if 1 did get called then 2 should be OK. You do need to have a UINavigationController to use 'push'. I've updated the answer.

Comment: this project doesn't use storyboards. tried the code here, not quite there yet: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20831791/navigation-controller-how-to-add-in-another-view-controller-in-xcode . I thinking I need something in my app controller file.

Comment: It's very easy to create a navigation controller programatically. The question and answer you mentioned described it well. Just follow that.

Answer (score 0):

Have you wired up your button's TouchUpInside event to your showSettings: method? This is normally done in Interface Builder with a control-drag. If you set a breakpoint on the first line of showSettings:, do you hit the breakpoint when you press the button? If not this is likely your issue.

Comment: Its hooked up. I have an alert inside the function showSettings() and the alert will run before or after the code inside the function.

Comment: perhaps your navigationController is null. As an aside, it is well worth the time to learn some debugger commands. You can stop on a breakpoint inside showSettings (it's a showSettings: method, not a showSettings() function) and in the debugger type "po self.navigationController" for example, to inspect the current state during a run...

Comment: well thats cool thx. looks like i need a navigation controller. perhaps you know of a good link in here, I've tried learning this stuff form the apple libraries but their samples always seem to yield piles of errors.

Comment: It's often a good way to go to work through a book that has lots of samples first, with online source code you can download and play with. Eventually you have to deal with reading Apple references though I know they don't give you step-by-step directions. Here is the class reference for UINavigationController:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: I agree, I need to get a good book and will. I'm a one man shop, and my client is good people but can't afford to hire an app developer. So off I went. And those class reference pages are what confuses me...I need to understand the syntax and some basics before those will be useful to me.

Comment: be prepared for a long learning curve and some painful head-banging days of debugging ahead... I can't say I found iOS to be the most simple, forgiving environment. But good luck!